# jQuery AjaxForm plugin have to submit twice

Tags: submit, ajaxform, ajaxsubmit

I am trying to use the ajaxForm plugin to submit a form via ajax.  The problem I am having is that I need to submit the form twice to actually get the form to submit.  See code  below, and I appreciate any help.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.submit-btn', function () {
    alert('Please wait...');
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('button.submit-btn').attr('disabled', true);
    }, 50)
    $('#send-form').ajaxForm(function() { 
      var currentAlert = $.jAlert('current');
      currentAlert.closeAlert();
      successAlert('Success!', 'The form has been submitted');
      $('button.submit-btn').attr('disabled', false);
    }); 
});

 <form action="" method="post" id="send-form">
     <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" name="send-modal-form" value="submit"></button>
 </form>
```

I tried to change it to ajaxSubmit and then add e.preventDefault(); but then the form doesn't submit  at all when I try.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have severals errors

1) the submit button and try ajax submit

use type button or a link 
when you click a submit button the browser try to send the form automatically and you are running a js but that's not prevent submit

2) use alert instead jAlert

change alert to jAlert

3) this code initialize the observer that execute the ajax

```
 $('#send-form').ajaxForm(function() { 
      var currentAlert = $.jAlert('current');
      currentAlert.closeAlert();
      successAlert('Success!', 'The form has been submitted');
      $('button.submit-btn').attr('disabled', false);
    });
```

then you add it on click but you must add it on document load
so here are the code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#send-form').ajaxForm(function() { 
      var currentAlert = $.jAlert('current');
      currentAlert.closeAlert();
      successAlert('Success!', 'The form has been submitted');
      $('button.submit-btn').attr('disabled', false);
    }); 
});

$(document).on('click', 'input.submit-btn', function () {
    jAlert('Please wait...','Please wait...');
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('button.submit-btn').attr('disabled', true);
    }, 50)
});
```

here is the HTML

```
 <form action="" method="post" id="send-form">
     <input type="button" class="submit-btn" name="send-modal-form" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your correction and unfortunately it still requires two clicks  to submit.

Comment: My correction fix one problem, the second problem is that you launch the browser alert //    alert('Please wait...');
instead a jAlert and after that you want get it with jAlert
      var currentAlert = $.jAlert('current');

Comment: Hi @Emiliano the alert is not the problem.  alert is shorthand for another plugin that I use.  When i change the input type to button, the form won't submit at all now.

Comment: remember change the selection on click event
$(document).on('click', 'input.submit-btn', function () {

Comment: I did.  In your answer, 'button.submit-btn' still exists as well.  And I changed that to input.submit-btn.

Comment: @LearntoExcel I believe that I improve my answer

Comment: I am sorry and I appreciate your help but the form doesn't submit at all now.  I also don't see why you have the form submit on document ready.  I don't want it to submit until the input button is clicked.